# Winforms - How to prevent Listbox item selection

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In WinForms I occationally have a loop running over a Listbox selecting Items.

During that time I don't want the user to select items in that listbox with the mouse or keys.

I looked at MyListbox.enabled=false but it grays out all items. Dont't want that.

How to prevent selecting items in a Listbox?

Answer (score 7):

I too wanted a read only list box, and finally, after much searching, found this from http://ajeethtechnotes.blogspot.com/2009/02/readonly-listbox.html:

```
public class ReadOnlyListBox : ListBox
{
    private bool _readOnly = false;
    public bool ReadOnly
    {
        get { return _readOnly; }
        set { _readOnly = value; }
    }

    protected override void DefWndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        // If ReadOnly is set to true, then block any messages 
        // to the selection area from the mouse or keyboard. 
        // Let all other messages pass through to the 
        // Windows default implementation of DefWndProc.
        if (!_readOnly || ((m.Msg <= 0x0200 || m.Msg >= 0x020E)
        && (m.Msg <= 0x0100 || m.Msg >= 0x0109)
        && m.Msg != 0x2111
        && m.Msg != 0x87))
        {
            base.DefWndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly - I would presume that you would want a ReadOnlyListBox to default _readOnly to true, would you not?

Answer (score 6):

Switch the [Listbox.SelectionMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectionmode.aspx) property to [SelectionMode.None](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.selectionmode.aspx)

**Edit**
As i see setting to  [SelectionMode.None](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.selectionmode.aspx) deselects all previously selected items and throws an exception if [SetSelected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.setselected.aspx) is called on the Listbox.

I think the desired behaviour is not possible (without wanting to gray out the items with `Enabled=false`).

Comment: If I do that my loop which is running at that time will not be able to select items. Remember i want the loop to select items but not the user.

Comment: This works in my scenario: I don't want the user to be able to check items, but must be able to check them programmatially. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Create an event handler that removes focus from the Listbox and subscribe the handler to the Listbox's GotFocus event. That way, the user will never be able to select anything in the Listbox. The following line of code does that with an inline anonymous method:

```
txtBox.GotFocus += (object anonSender, EventArgs anonE) => { txtBox.Parent.Focus(); };
```

***Edit**: code explanation

Answer (score 1):

You may have some luck if you sub class the ListBox and override the OnMouseClick method:

```
public class CustomListBox : ListBox
{
    public bool SelectionDisabled = false;

    protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SelectionDisabled)
        {
            // do nothing.
        }
        else
        {
            //enable normal behavior
            base.OnMouseClick(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you may want to do better information hiding or class design, but thats the basic functionality. There may be other methods you need to override too.

Answer (score -1):

Because what the questioner needs is to prevent individual options from being clicked rather than disabling them overall.

this is my way:

```
public class XCheckListBox : ListBox
{
    public XCheckListBox()
    {
        this.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
    }

    public Pen ForeColorPen => new Pen(ForeColor);


    [Category("Misc"), Description("是否多选"), Browsable(true), DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool MultiCheck { get => base.SelectionMode != SelectionMode.One; set => base.SelectionMode = value ? SelectionMode.MultiSimple : SelectionMode.One; }


    protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Index < 0) return;

        var @checked = e.State.HasFlag(DrawItemState.Selected);
        var g = e.Graphics;
        var rectOfItem = e.Bounds;
        //g.FillRectangle(BackColorBrush, rectOfItem);//e.DrawBackground();


        //if the item state is selected them change the back color 
        if (@checked)
            e = new DrawItemEventArgs(e.Graphics,
                                      e.Font,
                                      e.Bounds,
                                      e.Index,
                                      e.State ^ DrawItemState.Selected,
                                      e.ForeColor,
                                     Color.LightSteelBlue);// SystemColors.InactiveBorder Color.Yellow  Choose the color

        // Draw the background of the ListBox control for each item.
        e.DrawBackground();

        var rectOfCheckBox = rectOfItem.CenterSquareBox().Padding(2, 2).SetX(1);
        g.DrawRectangle(ForeColorPen, rectOfCheckBox);

        var sizeBeforeText = new Size(1 + rectOfCheckBox.RightTop().X + 3, rectOfItem.Height);
        var rectOfText = new Rectangle(rectOfItem.X + sizeBeforeText.Width, rectOfItem.Y, rectOfItem.Width - sizeBeforeText.Width, rectOfItem.Height);

        var itemText = "";
        itemText = this.DesignMode ?
            this.Text
            : this.Items.Count > e.Index ?
                this.Items[e.Index]?.ToString() ?? ""
                : "";

        var cbxSize = rectOfCheckBox.Padding(3, 3);
        //CheckBoxRenderer.GetGlyphSize

        if (@checked && !DisableList.Contains(itemText))
            TextRenderer.DrawText(g, "✔", e.Font, rectOfCheckBox, this.ForeColor, TextFormatFlags.Left | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter);
        //ControlPaint.DrawCheckBox(e.Graphics, rectOfCheckBox, @checked ? ButtonState.Checked : ButtonState.Normal);
        ////CheckBoxRenderer.DrawCheckBox(g, cbxSize.Location, CheckBoxState.MixedNormal);


        TextRenderer.DrawText(g, itemText, e.Font, rectOfText, this.ForeColor, TextFormatFlags.Left | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter);

        // If the ListBox has focus, draw a focus rectangle around the selected item.
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();


    }

    protected override void OnSelectedValueChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        var uncheckedIdx = new List<int>();
        foreach (var selectItem in this.SelectedIndices)
        {
            var ckdIdx = selectItem as int?;
            if (ckdIdx == null || ckdIdx.Value < 0) continue;
            var ckdItem = this.Items[ckdIdx.Value] as string;
            if (ckdItem == null) continue;
            if (DisableList.Contains(ckdItem))
                uncheckedIdx.Add(ckdIdx.Value);
        }

        foreach (var ckIdx in uncheckedIdx)
            this.SetSelected(ckIdx, false);

        base.OnSelectedValueChanged(e);
    }


    public void SetDisable(string item, bool enable)
    {
        if (!enable)
            DisableList.AddOrIgnore(item);
        else
            DisableList.Remove(item);

    }



    public List<string> DisableList = new List<string>();

}


public static class SharpEx
{
    public static Point AddX(this Point _this, int x) => new Point(_this.X + x, _this.Y);
    public static Point AddY(this Point _this, int y) => new Point(_this.X, _this.Y + y);

    public static Point SetX(this Point _this, int x) => new Point(x, _this.Y);
    public static Point SetY(this Point _this, int y) => new Point(_this.X, y);


    public static Point[] CenterLineInLine(this Point[] _this, decimal persent)
    {
        var poffset = (1 - persent) / 2;

        var need = poffset;
        var remain = 1 - poffset;
        var p1 = _this[0];
        var p2 = _this[1];
        var pX1 = (int)(p1.X * remain + p2.X * need);
        var pY1 = (int)(p1.Y * remain + p2.Y * need);
        var pX2 = (int)(p1.X * need + p2.X * remain);
        var pY2 = (int)(p1.Y * need + p2.Y * remain);

        return new Point[] { new Point(pX1, pY1), new Point(pX2, pY2) };
    }


    public static Size AddWidth(this Size _this, int width)
    {
        return new Size(_this.Width + width, _this.Height);
    }


    public static Size AddHeight(this Size _this, int height)
    {
        return new Size(_this.Width, _this.Height + height);
    }

    public static Size AddWidthHeight(this Size _this, int width = 0, int height = 0)
    {
        return new Size(_this.Width + width, _this.Height + height);
    }

    public static Point Start(this Rectangle _this) => _this.Location;
    public static Point End(this Rectangle _this) => _this.Location.AddX(_this.Width).AddY(_this.Height);
    public static Point LeftDown(this Rectangle _this) => _this.Location.AddY(_this.Height);
    public static Point RightTop(this Rectangle _this) => _this.Location.AddX(_this.Width);

    public static Point[] StartEnd(this Rectangle _this) => new Point[] { _this.Start(), _this.End() };

    public static Line[] XLine(this Rectangle _this, int paddingLeftRight, decimal lengthPersend) => _this.DiagonalLine(paddingLeftRight, lengthPersend);

    public static Point[] LeftDownRightTop(this Rectangle _this) => new Point[] { _this.LeftDown(), _this.RightTop() };

    public static Point[] CenterLine(this Rectangle _this, bool HorizontalOrVertical, decimal lengthPersend)
    {
        var length = (int)(HorizontalOrVertical ? lengthPersend * _this.Width : lengthPersend * _this.Height);

        if (HorizontalOrVertical)
        {
            return CenterLineInLine(new Point[]{ _this.Location.AddY(_this.Height / 2),
                _this.Location.AddX(_this.Width).AddY(_this.Height / 2) }, lengthPersend);
        }
        else
        {
            return CenterLineInLine(new Point[]{ new Point(_this.X+ _this.Width / 2, _this.Y ),
            new Point(_this.X+_this.Height / 2, _this.Y +_this.Height ) }, lengthPersend);
        }
    }


    public static Rectangle CenterSquareBox(this Rectangle _this)
    {
        if (_this.Width == _this.Height) return _this;
        var centerSquareBoxWidth = Math.Min(_this.Width, _this.Height);
        var location = _this.OffsetX((_this.Width - centerSquareBoxWidth) / 2).OffsetY((_this.Height - centerSquareBoxWidth) / 2).Location;
        return new Rectangle(location, new Size(centerSquareBoxWidth, centerSquareBoxWidth));
    }

    public static Rectangle CenterSameBox(this Rectangle _this, Size size)
    {
        var x = _this.X + (_this.Width / 2 - size.Width / 2);
        var y = _this.Y + (_this.Height / 2 - size.Height / 2);
        return new(new(x, y), size);
    }

    public static Point CenterPoint(this Rectangle _this)
    {
        var x = _this.X + _this.Width / 2;
        var y = _this.Y + _this.Height / 2;
        return new(x, y);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// 对角线
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="_this"></param>
    /// <param name="paddingLeftRight"></param>
    /// <param name="lengthPersend"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Line[] DiagonalLine(this Rectangle _this, int paddingLeftRight, decimal lengthPersend)
    {
        _this = _this.Padding(paddingLeftRight);
        return new Line[] { new(_this.StartEnd().CenterLineInLine(lengthPersend)), new(_this.LeftDownRightTop().CenterLineInLine(lengthPersend)) };
    }

    public static Rectangle MarginKeepLocation(this Rectangle _this, int marginLeftRight = 0, int marginTopButtom = 0)
    {
        return _this.Padding(-marginLeftRight, -marginTopButtom).OffsetXY(marginLeftRight, marginTopButtom);
    }
    public static Rectangle Margin(this Rectangle _this, int marginLeftRight = 0, int marginTopButtom = 0)
    {
        return _this.Padding(-marginLeftRight, -marginTopButtom);
    }

    public static Rectangle Margin2(this Rectangle _this, int left = 0, int right = 0, int top = 0, int buttom = 0)
    {
        return _this.Padding2(-left, -right, top, buttom);
    }


    public static Rectangle Margin2KeepLocation(this Rectangle _this, int left = 0, int right = 0, int top = 0, int buttom = 0)
    {
        return _this.Padding2(-left, -right, top, buttom).OffsetXY(left, top);
    }


    public static Rectangle Padding(this Rectangle _this, int paddingLeftRight = 0, int paddingTopButtom = 0)
    {
        return new Rectangle(_this.Location.AddX(paddingLeftRight).AddY(paddingTopButtom),
            new Size(_this.Width - paddingLeftRight * 2, _this.Height - paddingTopButtom * 2));
    }

    public static Rectangle Padding2(this Rectangle _this, int left = 0, int right = 0, int top = 0, int buttom = 0)
    {
        return new Rectangle(_this.Location.AddX(left).AddY(top),
            new Size(_this.Width - (left + right), _this.Height - (top + buttom)));
    }

    public static Rectangle Padding(this Rectangle _this, Padding padding)
    {
        return new Rectangle(_this.Location.AddX(padding.Left).AddY(padding.Top),
            new Size(_this.Width - (padding.Left + padding.Right), _this.Height - (padding.Top + padding.Bottom)));
    }

    public static Rectangle SetX(this Rectangle _this, int setX) => new Rectangle(new Point(setX, _this.Location.Y), _this.Size);
    public static Rectangle SetY(this Rectangle _this, int setY) => new Rectangle(new Point(_this.Location.X, setY), _this.Size);

    public static Rectangle OffsetX(this Rectangle _this, int offsetX) => new Rectangle(_this.Location.AddX(offsetX), _this.Size);
    public static Rectangle OffsetY(this Rectangle _this, int offsetY) => new Rectangle(_this.Location.AddY(offsetY), _this.Size);

    public static Rectangle OffsetWidth(this Rectangle _this, int offsetWidth) => new Rectangle(_this.Location, new Size(_this.Size.Width + offsetWidth, _this.Size.Height));
    public static Rectangle OffsetHeight(this Rectangle _this, int offsetHeight) => new Rectangle(_this.Location, new Size(_this.Size.Width, _this.Size.Height + offsetHeight));


    public static Rectangle OffsetSize(this Rectangle _this, int offsetWidth, int offsetHeight) => _this.OffsetWidthHeight(offsetWidth, offsetHeight);

    public static Rectangle OffsetWidthHeight(this Rectangle _this, int offsetWidth, int offsetHeight) => new Rectangle(_this.Location, new Size(_this.Size.Width + offsetWidth, _this.Size.Height + offsetHeight));

    public static Rectangle OffsetXY(this Rectangle _this, int offsetX, int offsetY) => new Rectangle(_this.Location.AddX(offsetX).AddY(offsetY), _this.Size);

    public static Padding SetLeft(this Padding _this, int left) => new Padding(left, _this.Top, _this.Right, _this.Bottom);
    public static Padding SetTop(this Padding _this, int top) => new Padding(_this.Left, top, _this.Right, _this.Bottom);
    public static Padding SetRight(this Padding _this, int right) => new Padding(_this.Left, _this.Top, right, _this.Bottom);
    public static Padding SetBottom(this Padding _this, int bottom) => new Padding(_this.Left, _this.Top, _this.Right, bottom);

    public static Padding OffsetLeft(this Padding _this, int offsetLeft) => _this.SetLeft(_this.Left + offsetLeft);
    public static Padding OffsetTop(this Padding _this, int offsetTop) => _this.SetTop(_this.Top + offsetTop);
    public static Padding OffsetRight(this Padding _this, int offsetRight) => _this.SetRight(_this.Right + offsetRight);
    public static Padding OffsetBottom(this Padding _this, int offsetBottom) => _this.SetBottom(_this.Left + offsetBottom);

}


public struct Line
{
    public Line(int xStart, int yStart, int xEnd, int yEnd)
    {
        XStart = xStart;
        YStart = yStart;
        XEnd = xEnd;
        YEnd = yEnd;
    }

    public Line(Point start, Point end)
    {
        XStart = start.X;
        YStart = start.Y;
        XEnd = end.X;
        YEnd = end.Y;
    }

    public Line(Point[] startEnd)
    {
        XStart = startEnd[0].X;
        YStart = startEnd[0].Y;
        XEnd = startEnd[1].X;
        YEnd = startEnd[1].Y;
    }

    public int XStart;
    public int YStart;
    public int XEnd;
    public int YEnd;
    public Point Start => new Point(XStart, YStart);
    public Point End => new Point(XEnd, YEnd);

    public static implicit operator Point[](Line line)
    {
        return new Point[2] { line.Start, line.End };
    }
}


public static class ObjectEx
{

    public static ICollection<T> AddOrIgnore<T>(this ICollection<T> _this, params T[] items)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
            if (!_this.Contains(item))
                _this.Add(item);

        return _this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to keep your answer focused on just the answer.  Downvotes happen.

Comment: Your answer does not include references to those `CenterSquareBox` and `AddOrIgnore` extensions.

Comment: I added the rest of the code.